# App.run_server() does not display my dash table and produces error

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

When i run the below: (where data is just a pandas dataframe)

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in data.columns],
    data=data.to_dict('records'),

)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True,ssl_context='adhoc')
```

i then get a : 'running on https://127.0.0.1:8050/ and then when i click on it i get a “hmm… can’t reach this page” and an error code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

how can i resolve this? 127.0.0.1 is already added to my trusted site. i have also tried specifying a random port number but nothing.

Comment: May I ask please. What Operating System are you using?

Comment: @Nsukami windows 10 enterprise, OS build 17134.1006

Comment: Post the full script.  You currently don't show where you define the df or what it looks like.

Comment: @manwithfewneeds i would but it doesn't matter what data frame is defined, i get the same issue. So I can rule out my data frame being the issue.

Comment: Did you try switching to a different browser?

Comment: @manwithfewneeds i have tried switching browsers and still nothing

Comment: Google the error you're getting.  It's a Windows 10 specific error.  There are guides that walk u through how to fix